# Is it possible to use my Power BI embed token only on the server?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a web application with user authentication. I want to embed some Power BI reports in my application without the need my users to have registered accounts for Power BI. I found [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/App%20Owns%20Data) in the documentation and it is working just fine, but there is something that bothers me: As far as I understood from the documentation the embed token is reusable (cacheable), so it would not be hard for a user to get the embed token and use it to load the report outside of my application. Is there a possibility I do transfer all of the data via the server and not to use the JavaScript API at all?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The EmbedToken is limited in duration (up to an hour currently).
It can be cached but would not work past its expiration time.

You can view the expiration for each EmbedToken in the `/GenerateToken` response.

```json
{                
    "expiration":"{expiration}",  
    "token":"{token}",  
    "tokenId":"{tokenId}"  
}
```

As described in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt784614.aspx

When using the C# library from Power BI you will use it as:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets expiration time of token - in UTC.
/// </summary>
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "expiration")]
public System.DateTime? Expiration { get; set; }
```

from:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp/blob/42fe61f0b083ce7803893e74975216467ad82f65/sdk/PowerBI.Api/Source/V2/Models/EmbedToken.cs#L56

The EmbedToken however, can be used ONLY to embed certain artifacts using the JS SDK, so any data manipulations in the service are not allowed